# PCA analysis in a loop for certain column intervals in R

Tags: r, loops, pca

I have a data set containing 526 rows nd 560 columns. In this data set, I want to run pca analysis for each 16 columns, respectively, in the loop and save the PCA scores for each row. I tried the below code but it did not work. I would be happy to get your advice.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {       
  df[ , i:(i+15)] <- prcomp(df[, i:(i+15)], scale. = TRUE, center = T)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with a `lapply` loop. Create a vector `f` of consecutive integers, each repeated 16 times. Then split the data.frame names by this vector and `lapply` function `prcomp` to each subset. Finally, extract the scores.

```
f <- c(1, rep(0, 15))
f <- rep(f, length(names(df1))/16)
f <- cumsum(f)
nms <- split(names(df1), f)

pca_list <- lapply(nms, function(x){
  prcomp(df1[x], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
})
scores_list <- lapply(pca_list, '[[', 'x')
```

---

### Test data creation code

```
set.seed(2021)
df1 <- replicate(560, rnorm(526))
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
```